# How do I get Chrome to accept downloads from my .NET app?

Tags: google-chrome, mime

I have a .NET app that generates PDFs and XLSes within code, as well as being able to download DOCXs and XLSXes stored in a database table. Edge has no problem allowing me to download (or, for that matter, open in Acrobat Reader / Word / Excel as appropriate) the generated files. However, Chrome does something strange.

When I try to download a DOCX or XLSX, it doesn't give me an option to open it; it just brings up the standard Windows "Save As" dialog box, and when I enter a filename and select "Save," nothing appears to happen. However, Windows Explorer shows the file in its "Recent" list, which makes me think that at least a file entry was created, and then deleted. The file does not appear in Chrome's Downloads page.

When I try to create a PDF, it appears correctly in its own tab. However, when I click on the "Download" icon, first it says that the download failed with a "Network Error," but allows me to resume; when I resume, eventually it says that the download was "Blocked." These download attempts do appear on Chrome's Downloads page.

My Chrome download security setting is "Safe Browsing with Standard Protection." Also, File Handlers is set to, "Web apps can ask to open types of files."

What should I be checking on Chrome to allow file downloads?

Here is the code used to send the file to the web browser:

```
// byte[] SomeReportContent is the file content
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = True;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SomeReport.pdf");
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
// * Other ContentType values:
// application/msword  (DOC)
// application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document  (DOCX)
// application/xls  (XLS)
// application/vnd.ms-excel  (XLS)
// application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet  (XLSX)
Response.BinaryWrite(SomeReport_Content);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is not with .NET, but with Chrome. When I changed the settings to download PDFs instead of opening them in Chrome's internal PDF viewer, suddenly all of my downloads started working properly.